# Laravel - problem with extra favicon in url

Tags: laravel, url

I have a little problem with my URL in the main page of the website, There is a `favicon.ico` in URL

```
http://example.com/favicon.ico
```

Why there is a `favicon.ico`? How can I remove this **from url** ?

**Update**

I have not any `favicon.ico` in public folder. I have another `favicon.png` in another folder

Comment: The favicon is located in `public/favicon.ico`. Delete that

Comment: Thank you but i want remove favicon from url .... and still show this @aceraven777

Answer (score 1):

just remove the code from your main page

< link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" >
or 
delete favicon.ico file located in public/favicon.ico

Comment: Removing the link is the better solution, Just deleting the favicon will make the page return 404 which can negatively effect SEO.

Comment: it is cache problem 
try in incognito using ctrl+shift+N

Answer (score 1):

to change the favicon :

1. replace the `favicon.ico` in the root folder
2. set version of the favicon `http://www.example.com/favicon.ico?v=2`

to remove it:

1. delete favicon.ico in the root folder
2. remove the line `<link rel="icon" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: try to clean your browser cache or try another browser after you delete the code and the file ....